# Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object - pretty sure sql query is correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've searched on SO already for an answer to my problem, without any luck. As far as I can tell, there should be no problems with my sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM scores WHERE `primary_id`=$id;
```

I definitely have a table called "scores" with a column called "primary_id", and I can perform inserts, updates etc on it with no problems.
However whenever I try to perform a select, I get the "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object" error.
All of the posts I've seen suggest it is caused by the sql query failing and returning false. The odd thing is, that even though the while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) throws an error, it still performs the update query contained inside. Maybe that's not odd to someone more experienced, but to me if the "while" call fails I wouldn't expect the contents to be executed, especially seeing as it somehow still gets the fields from $row.

Here is the code.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$currentWeek = date("W");
$currentMonth = date("m");        

$sql = "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE primary_id=$id;";
$result = $this->db->query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Something went wrong: '.$mysqli->error());
}
else
{
    echo "result exists";//this successfully echoes, so $result must exist
}


while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    $week = $row['scoreweek'];
    $month = $row['scoremonth'];

    if($row['weekNumber'] != $currentWeek){
        $week = 0;
    }

    if($row['monthNumber'] != $currentMonth){
        $month = 0;
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE scores SET  `weekNumber` = $currentWeek, `monthNumber` = $currentMonth, `scoreweek` = $week + $score, `scoremonth` = $month + $score, `scoreall` = `scoreall` + $score WHERE `primary_id` = $id;";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Have I missed something obvious? I've tried the statement with and without apostrophes in various places, but with no luck.

Edit: calling var_dump($result) gives me the following:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) {
["current_field"]=>
int(0)
["field_count"]=>
int(8)
["lengths"]=>
NULL
["num_rows"]=>
int(1)
["type"]=>
int(0)
}
```

Comment: Echo out your `$sql`. Does it work when you run it in the database? Also, your `trigger_error` call is running `mysql_error`, but the rest of your code looks like it's using mysqli_*.

Comment: Also, try a `var_dump($result)` to see what's actually in there.

Comment: May be `$this->db` is not an object of `mysqli`

Comment: As **andrewsi** already pointed you are mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_`, also you call `$mysqli->error();` as a function but it is actually a property: `$mysqli->error;`. Also, once you `trigger_error()` script is not executed from this point forward so basically checking `if (!$result) {...}` is pointless

Comment: andrewsi: if I run the code directly in my database, it works fine. Actually, an almost identical query in another function also works. Also I changed mysql_error to mysqli_error with no effect.

Comment: added my var_dump output to my original post

Comment: are you sure that the line `while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){` is where the error is generated?

Comment: spencer7593 has worked it out for me, thanks anyways everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that last line

```
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
```

That's overwriting the value of `$result` that was previously assigned, which you're fetching from at the top of the loop. (It's likely the first execution of the `$result->fetch_assoc()` is working fine, and execution of the loop body is probably fine. It's when the execution finishes the loop body, and goes back to the top of the loop, that's when the error is being thrown.)

Change that to a different variable name, so that the current value of `$result` is preserved.

---

A note on an entirely different issue, with msyqli_, you can make use of parameterized queries, to avoid including variables in the SQL text, and the potential for SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

If you are going to include variables in the SQL text (like your code above does), you should be making use of the mysqli_real_escape_string function.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

"This function is used to create a legal SQL string that you can use in an SQL statement."

Comment: Thank you, that was it! I can't believe I'd missed something so simple.